# Connecting to a remote MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am trying to create a connection between my test WPF application and a MySql (phpmyadmin) database. 
Right now, I tried every suggestions from other topics with similar problems, none worked.

I have an user with all privileges(http://prntscr.com/ehhrdv) and one dummy table.

My connection code looks like this:

```
string conectionString = "Server = r310.reseller.si; Database = ******; Uid = ******; Pwd = ******";



         myConnection = new MySqlConnection(conectionString);

        try { myConnection.Open(); } catch(MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

The error I'm getting:

```
 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at WpfApplication2.MainWindow.pressMe_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Tomi\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 51
```

I am not sure wether my user has no privileges for a remote  connection or something else.

I am managing the database from my job's reseller website.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};

at the beginning of the connection string, ie:

string conectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=r310.reseller.si;Database=******;Uid=******;Pwd=******";

Comment: Have you checked your firewall? Could be a firewall issue

Comment: What specifically should I check?

Comment: Your outbound ports might be getting blocked. Try deactivating your firewall completely and running the program again. If it works, then it could be a firewall issue.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. Will report back results when I can

Comment: Aparently my user doesn't have enough privileges. I'll need to ask the domain owner to give me full permission. Hopefully it'll work then